# Async and multiple async database calls

Tags: node.js, node-async

I use async lib in my node/mongoose app and got some problems I dont understand. I got this peice of code:

```
var model_1;
async.series([
    function (callback) {
        Model1.findOne( {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(model1_id)}, function (err, model1) {
            if (err) {
                callaback(err);
            } else {
                model_1 = model1;
                callback();
            }
        });
    },
    function (callback) {
        async.forEach(req.body.myArray, function (element, callback) {
                model2              = new Model2();
                model2.name         = element.name;
                Model3.findOne( { _id: element.model3_id }, function (err, model3) {
                    if (err) {
                        callaback(err);
                    } else {
                        Model4.findOne( { _id: element.model4_id }, function (err, model_4) {
                            data.push({
                                    model_1:    model_1,
                                    model_2:    model_2,
                                    model_3:    model_3,
                                    model_4:    model_4,
                                });
                                callback();
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        }, function (err) { /* callback for async.forEach */
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    console.log(i+": m2 id: "+data[i].model_2._id);
                    console.log(i+": m3 id: "+data[i].model_3._id);
                    console.log(i+": m4 id: "+data[i].model_4._id);
                }
            }
        });
}], function (err) { /* callback for async.series */
    if (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

And my json body looks like

```
{
    model1_id: XXXX,
    myArray: [
        {model3_id: YYYY_1, model4_id: ZZZZ_1},
        {model3_id: YYYY_2, model4_id: ZZZZ_2},
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

The problem I get is that in the async.forEach callback when i print data is that model_2.id is the same for all elements, model_3 and model_4 ids is the same as in myArray and OK but I get the same model_2 object on all positions in the data variabel. How to fix this? Can I pass model_2 to my find call?

Answer (score 0):

Do this without "var" in front in async.forEach()'s callback makes model2 global:

```
model2 = new Model2();
```

async.forEach() processes entries in req.body.myArray in parallel (not series), so it loops through all the entries very fast without waiting for Model3.findOne() to finish and push the data into the array.  That's why you're getting same value for model2.  You need to add "var" in front of model2 as below so that each iteration of the loop has it's own copy of model2 and therefore will not be overwritten when it loops through req.body.myArray:

```
var model2 = new Model2();
```

Another option is to use async.eachSeries() which processes req.body.myArray in series so that model2 won't be overwritten.